# SO_SNDBUF and SO_RCVBUF on Linux sockets

Tags: c, sockets, linux-kernel

I am programming a client server application. Simply, the server can use either UDP or TCP for each client.

I want both the TCP client and UDP client to print the default value for 
`SO_SNDBUF` and `SO_RCVBUF`, but I am surprised when I print the default value for sndbuf and rcvbuf before the connection establishment the value is 0.

**Note**: I am using Ubuntu 12.10

Here is my code:

```
//assume all variables initialized correctly.

/* SO_RCVBUF options */

len = sizeof(rcvbuf);
getsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &rcvbuf, &len);
len = sizeof(mss);
getsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_MAXSEG, &mss, &len);
printf("defaults: SO_RCVBUF = %d, MSS = %d\n", rcvbuf, mss);

rcvbuf = 9973;      /* a prime number */
setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &rcvbuf, sizeof(rcvbuf));
len = sizeof(rcvbuf);
getsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &rcvbuf, &len);
printf("SO_RCVBUF = %d (after setting it to 9973)\n\n\n\n", rcvbuf); 


/* SO_RCVBUF options */


/* SO_SNDBUF options */

len2 = sizeof(sndbuf);
getsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &sndbuf, &len2);
//len2 = sizeof(mss2);
getsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_MAXSEG, &mss2, &len2);
printf("defaults: SO_SNDBUF = %d, MSS = %d\n", sndbuf, mss2);

sndbuf = 9979;      /* a prime number */
setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &sndbuf, sizeof(sndbuf));
len2 = sizeof(sndbuf);
getsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &sndbuf, &len2);
printf("SO_SNDBUF = %d (after setting it to 9979)\n", sndbuf);

/* SO_SNDBUF options */
```

**Sample output:**

> defaults: SO_RCVBUF = 0, MSS = 0
>
> SO_RCVBUF = 9973 (after setting it to 9973)
>
> defaults: SO_SNDBUF = 0, MSS = 0
>
> SO_SNDBUF = 9979 (after setting it to 9979)
>
> tcp_time nes411_server
>
> Current time is (TCP): Mon Apr 22 23:40:46 2013

After connection:

> SO_SNDBUF = 170840, MSS = 16384

Comment: udp default "should" be like 40K try this code: https://gist.github.com/rdp/8198697

Answer (score 3):

Obviously the send buffer and receive buffer are allocated when you call `connect(),` not before. You could be about to use the socket for listening, in which case both buffers would be a complete waste of space. Or for nothing, ditto.

NB Why are you using a prime number? It's customary to use powers of two for buffer sizes.

Answer (score 0):

you can check from below code default socket buffer.

```
int rcvBufferSize;
int sockOptSize = sizeof(rcvBufferSize);
getsockopt(udp_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &rcvBufferSize, &sockOptSize);
printf("initial socket receive buf %d\n", rcvBufferSize);
```

https://gist.github.com/rdp/8198697

Comment: He's already doing this. His question is about the values obtained.