# What size buffer should be used for reading from a UDP socket?

Tags: sockets, udp, size, rust, buffer

When reading data from a [`std::net::UdpSocket`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.UdpSocket.html) in Rust we use a buffer:

```
fn recv_from(&self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<(usize, SocketAddr)>
```

How big should this buffer be? Is the socket a stream or a datagram?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a size one larger than the largest expected datagram. That way, if you receive one that size, you know there was a protocol error and that data may have been truncated.

You will receive one datagram at a time. It's not a stream.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use the receive/transmit buffer sizes that match the socket receive/transmit options, see [SO_SNDBUF and SO_RCVBUF on Linux sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156326/so-sndbuf-and-so-rcvbuf-in-c-sockets-under-linux), `getsockopt(3)`, `SO_RCVBUF`, and `SO_SNDBUF`.

Alternatively, you may use buffer sizes that match and align well with your protocol structures.

The larger the buffer size in your program is, the less IO calls you perform. In the case where you assemble payload from multiple disjoint memory locations, you may use scatter / gather IO vectors to minimize IO syscalls.

Comment: Yes, it's obvious that size of buffer should correlate with protocols structures. However multiple incoming messages can accumulate in system UDP buffer before my function (that handles read event) will be called. So it's impossible to predict what size is enough.

Comment: How can I get SO_SNDBUF and SO_RCVBUF in Rust? In case of using dynamically allocated buffers it will be necessary to use heap that makes performance worse.

Comment: With UDP, you will only receive one datagram per read operation, so unless you have messages split over multiple datagrams you should be able to size your buffer based on message size.