# How do I poll a std::net::UdpSocket?

Tags: io, network-programming, rust

With Rust's [UdpSocket](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.UdpSocket.html), it appears to only have `send()`, `recv()`, and `set_nonblocking(bool)`. This is a rather limited set of functions, e.g. it would be nice to have `recv()` which always blocks until a packet is received and `recv_nonblocking()` which never blocks, and maybe even `recv_callback()` that calls a function when a packet is received.

Is there any way to do `recv_nonblocking()` other than something insane like this:

```
fn recv_nonblocking(socket: &UdpSocket, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize> {

    try!(socket.set_nonblocking(true));

    // By the way, how do I know how big to make my buffer?
    // There doesn't seem to be any way to know the size of a packet
    // before it is returned by socket.recv().

    let res = socket.recv(&mut buf);

    // This isn't really right either because there is no get_nonblocking()
    // so we can't reliably restore the previous state.
    try!(socket.set_nonblocking(false));

    res
}
```

Would that even work?

Comment: *how do I know how big to make my buffer* — well, you'd probably use the `buf` passed in, not create your own. You should probably at least try compiling the code.

Comment: Ha yes, true. I forgot I passed one in. The question remains though: How would the called know how big to make it?

Comment: As a 20k rep user, you already know that you should only ask [one question per question, though](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/281829). That way, we can [mark it as a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36333976/155423). ^_^

Answer (score 3):

## recv_nonblocking

Just call `set_nonblocking` and then `recv`. If you're really going to use both blocking and nonblocking I/O on the same socket, you can write trivial wrapper functions:

```
fn recv_nonblocking(this: &UdpSocket, buf: &mut [u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
    this.set_nonblocking(true);
    this.recv(buf)
}
```

## recv_callback

Good asynchronous I/O primitives have been left out of the standard library, so that the design work can be iterated on without locking down to the stability guarantees and release cycle of the language.

The crate to look at is [mio](https://crates.io/crates/mio).

Answer (score 0):

Generally you either use blocking or non-blocking mode through the whole lifecycle of the socket. In blocking mode you can use `set_read_timeout` `get_read_timeout` instead.